# Difference between Indian scale and western

Tags: theory

Are Indian fundamental scale notes different than western music scale? If yes by what percentage?

Comment: What do you mean by percentage?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on which Indian scales you are referring to, Hindustani or Carnatic (the only 2 I know).

I can say that the Carnatic scales include most of the Western scales as a sub set.  I will not go into the compete details of these except to say that Carnatic scales are based on the 12TET chromatic scale and the fundamental scales are 7 tone (not including octave) and usually have either the P4 or P5 in them (I want to say P4 but I forget and do not have my text at hand).  Other than that one is free to place any combination of the 2, 3, 6, and 7, and the other perfect interval.  With all this freedom in place one can create up to 72 scales.  Most of these do not appear in Western music but the Major scale, Dorian, Phygian, Mixolydian, Minor, Melodic minor ascending, are part of that set.

Based on memory I think that some of the Hindustani Ragas might include note bending by a 1/4 tone that introduces notes outside the 12TET spectrum.  However, I have been told by Indian musicians that those are embellishments and that the basic patterns are just {Do, Re, Mi, Fa, Sol, La, Ti, Do}.  I cannot give a first hand account of this.

Comment: Are they really 12-tone equal temperament, or are they some sort of acoustical just scale?  If the latter, how do they match or diverge from European just scales?